# Multiple table authentication in laravel5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I am using larave 5.I already use laravel auth and it works nicely.I have two tables user and company.But now i can only auth using user table.How can i make another authentication using company.It is not possible for now merge them in a single table.

Comment: Why would someone authenticate as an entire company? Shouldn't users be members of a company and always authenticate with their individual accounts?

Comment: @ceejayoz users and company have individual login information in individual table.

Comment: Why not you introduce a column named as `usertype` because having two user table is not a recommended one in laravel

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen did you read?i mentioned "It is not possible for now merge them in a single table."

Comment: @user3621494 : Then you should do authentication manually then set session for it and to proceed with it. You need to know how to do that ?

Comment: No.I can able to auth manually.But i need to know multi auth with multi table in laravel.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel I have seen your question here look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294832/laravel-5-1-multiple-authentication/32296166#32296166 it might inspire you. best luck