# How to make user, and roles relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables :

```
User ->
  id : 
  name : 
  role_id : ->references('id')->on('roles');

Roles ->
  id :
  role_name :
  access :
```

I am trying to access roles details from user.

My User model has:

```php
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

My Role model has:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

When I try to do following :

```php
$user = User::find(1);

$details = [
    'name' => $user->first_name,
    'role' => $user->role->role_name
];
```

I get error :

> Trying to get property of non-object

My roles table contains access columns containing array of permissions to different routes. So my user will have only one role. While a role can have multiple users.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem, i was having a role column in user table, so when i was doing

```
$user->role->role_name
```

it was fetching `role` column instead of relationship.

Comment: You could also use `$user->role()->role_name` to distinguish relationships from attributes.

Comment: I am learning  laravel and this is a good point. +1 @HarryGeo

Answer (score 12):

In my recent project, I handled these requirement in that way..
First of All Database Table Structure/Migration

### User Table

```
class CreateUserTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('notify')->default(0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('user');
    }

}
```

### Role Table

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRoleTable extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('role');
    }

}
```

### Role And User Relation Table

```
class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        // Create table for associating roles to users (Many-to-Many)
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('role_user');
    }

}
```

After these table you have to handle permission by assigning to specific Role.

### Permission

```
class Permission extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('permission', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('pattern');
            $table->string('target');
            $table->string('module');
            $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('permission');
    }

}
```

### Permission and Role Table Relation

```
class PermissionRole extends Migration {
    public function up() {
        // Create table for associating roles to permission (Many-to-Many)
        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permission')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('role')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('permission_role');
    }

}
```

And Finally our model would look alike:

### User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'is_admin'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->whereStatus('1');
    }
    public function scopeAdmin($query) {
        return $query->whereIsAdmin('1');
    }
    public function scopeNotify($query) {
        return $query->whereNotify('1');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function attachRole($role) {
        if (is_object($role)) {
            $role = $role->getKey();
        }
        if (is_array($role)) {
            $role = $role['id'];
        }
        $this->roles()->attach($role);
    }

    public function detachRole($role) {
        if (is_object($role)) {
            $role = $role->getKey();
        }
        if (is_array($role)) {
            $role = $role['id'];
        }
        $this->roles()->detach($role);
    }

    public function attachRoles($roles) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->attachRole($role);
        }
    }

    public function detachRoles($roles) {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->detachRole($role);
        }
    }

    public function isSuperUser() {
        return (bool)$this->is_admin;
    }

    public function hasAccess($permissions, $all = true) {
        if ($this->isSuperUser()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $this->hasPermission($permissions, $all);
    }

    public function hasPermission($permissions) {
        $mergedPermissions = $this->getMergedPermissions();
        //dd($mergedPermissions);
        if (!is_array($permissions)) {
            $permissions = (array)$permissions;
        }

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            $matched = false;
            // We will set a flag now for whether this permission was
            // matched at all.
            $founded_perms = find_in($mergedPermissions, "name", $permission);
            if (!empty($founded_perms)) {
                $matched = true;
            }

        }

        if ($matched === false) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getMergedPermissions() {
        $permissions = array();
        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $group) {
            $permissions = array_merge($permissions, $group->permissions()->get()->toArray());
        }
        return $permissions;
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        $roles = [];
        if ($this->roles()) {
            $roles = $this->roles()->get();
        }
        return $roles;
    }
}
```

### Role Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'role';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'display_name', 'description'];

    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->whereStatus('1');
    }

    /**
     * Many-to-Many relations with User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Permission");
    }

}
```

### Permission Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model {
    protected $table = 'permission';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'pattern', 'target', 'module', 'display_name', 'status'];

    public static function displayable() {
        $prepared_array = [];
        $temp = self::orderBy('module')->get()->toArray();
        foreach ($temp as $sin) {
            $prepared_array[$sin['module']][] = $sin;
        }
        return $prepared_array;
    }
    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->whereStatus('1');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Role");
    }
}
```

Well, thats the basic structure helped to implement basic ACL and Auth with laravel 5.

Let me know if you have any further related question. Or If you need complete implementation I'll provide it to you.

Comment: @Sadar could you explain this further? So what are the typical values in each table?

Comment: could you explain this further? So what are the typical values in each table?

Comment: @Daniel well, `user` for user related information, `role` and `permission` store roles like administration, subscriber etc and permission is the list of all permission you got under the system, user has role and roles has many permission. so, `role_user ` for user role relations and `permission_role` for check each roles what got to access.

Answer (score 6):

For a **[one-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)** relationship you don't need a pivot table, so you can delete the `user_roles` table. Then add a `role_id` column to your `users` table, that will reference the `id` column in for your `roles` table. Next define the relations as follows for each of your models:

```php
// User.php
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

and

```php
// Role.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Now you can access your role via the relation like this:

```php
$user->role->name;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My user will have only one role, so how is it many-to-many?

Comment: I deduced that you wanted many-to-many because you have a pivot table, which is of no use if you want one-to-many relationships. If you want a one to many relation, get rid of the `user_roles` table, and add a `role_id` columns in your users table. That will allow you to specify one role for each user.

Comment: Also what exactly doesn't work when you apply the change that I suggested? What's the error message?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes to your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i did those changes, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed you are not using the laravel default table naming conventions,
you are using user_roles whereass laravel naming conventions state you should use:
role_user  (alphabetical and singular)

you could override the belongsToMany by stating your custom table name ofcource.

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_roles');
}
```

on the second node there are also some good libraries to handle these kind of things, take a look at : https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look again. I am learning right now, so i will prefer to stay away from libraries for now.