# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable error in laravel5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 for my project. I am trying to authenticate my built in model instead of laravel's own User model.

```
My model name is Registration_Model
my table is registration
```

from [Laravel 5.1 multiple authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294832/laravel-5-1-multiple-authentication)
i did what he said. the auth.php file is

```php
     return [
'multi' => [
        'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\User::class,
        'table'  => 'users'
    ],
    'registration' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Registration_Model::class, // Model Class
        'table'  => 'registration' // registration table
    ],
 ],
 'password' => [
       'email' => 'emails.password',
       'table' => 'password_resets',
       'expire' => 60,
  ]
 ];
```

My route.php file is

```php
Route::resource('/', 'RegistrationController');
Route::get('register', function () {
    return view('project.register');
});
Route::post('route_register','RegistrationController@store');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthRegistrationController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthRegistrationController@postLogin');
// Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthRegistrationController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthRegistrationController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register','Auth\AuthRegistrationController@postRegister');
```

and my AuthRegistrationController.php file is

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController;
use App\Registration_Model;

class AuthRegistrationController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;  

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }  

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [

            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:registration',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:3',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Registration_Model::create([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    protected $redirectPath = 'register'; 
    protected $loginPath = '/auth/login';
}
```

and i am getting error message when try registration.

> 1. ErrorException in Guard.php line 430: Argument 1 passed to
>      Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of
>      Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>      App\Registration_Model given. and i am getting error message when try login
> 2. ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 110: Argument 1
>      passed to
>      Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be
>      an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance
>      of App\Registration_Model given, called in
>      C:\xampp\htdocs\project_2016\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate

\Auth\Guard.php
    on line 390 and defined
    and my Registration_Model is here

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Registration_Model extends Model
    {
         protected  $table = "registration";
        protected $primaryKey = "reg_id";

        protected $fillable = ['email','password'];
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `App\Registration_Model` class? It needs to implement the `Authenticatable` interface. Does it?

Comment: I have edited auth.php and post Registration_Model.but now when try to login i am redirected to auth/login again and again.