# Multi Auth in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I've used multi `Auth` concept in my `Laravel` project,
I had follow all step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294832/laravel-5-1-multiple-authentication/33565243#33565243) 
In this case my `Auth` attempt is working
`(Auth::attempt('inspector',$userdata))`, Is working fine, But when I'm trying to use `Auth` check it is not working, And it is not giving any error.

I use `(Auth::check('inspector'))` like this,

Could you please tell me how I can use auth check here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved issue, I use `isset` for my Dashboard page after first login,
This is the code I used at the starting of my Dashboard page `dahboard.blade.php`
code as below

```
if (isset(Auth::user('admin')->email))
{!! Auth::user('admin')->id !!}
endif
```

And after this I use `Auth::check()` in controller and it is working fine.